# .net project won't run in debugger because "unable to create a localhost TCP/IP connection"

Tags: visual-studio-2012

My project runs/debugs fine on my machine. On my partner's machine, which runs dozens of other shared projects fine, it fails with "The debugger was unable to create a localhost TCP/IP connection, which is required for 64-bit debugging".

Poking about a bit, setting the build to x86 "fixes" the problem, but that of course means it's running 32-bit on my machine when the code comes back.

Anyone know what would cause this and perhaps a better solution?

Comment: P.S. This is why we should all write good error messages.  "The debugger was unable to..." tells you what didn't happen.  But what DID happen?  What error or exception did the debugger receive when it tried?  Was it a port already in use error?  Was it an access denied error?  etc.

Comment: The 64-bit debugger cannot run in-process inside Visual Studio since VS is a 32-bit process.  Having trouble getting two processes to talk to each other is an environmental issue, almost always caused by anti-malware  Disable it and try again.

Comment: Ok thanks Hans, I'll see what I can find.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Did you find cause of the problem or a solution for it?

Comment: @RezaAghaei No I don't recall what caused it, although I do recall it not due to anti-malware. IIRC a reboot fixed it, which implies one side of the VS system was running 32 for some reason, while the other was 64.

Comment: For me this error seemed to be triggered by switching to a Public network on my Windows 7 system. Completely disabling the Windows Firewall did not help. Rebooting did.